# Duplicate a garage door key

Tags: virtualwire

I am trying to copy my garage door key. I opened it and found out it has dip switches which you can flip so you can send different codes. It uses 12 bits and operates at 315Mhz. I bought a 315Mhz transmitter for arduino and i am trying to send that 12 bit code. I used an RTL-SDR and found out that the key uses AM modulation. Now, the problem is i dont know how to send bits (1,0 or high and low). I connected vcc of the transmitter to arduino 5V and gnd to gnd. Data pin is connected to pin 9. I tried setting pin 9 high or low coresponding to the code with 2ms pause in beetwen but RTL-SDR showed that nothing was transmitted. I tried using rc_switch and virtual_wire libary and using diffferent transmitters in case this one was damaged but no success. So how do i actually send high and low signals with these transmitters?
PS: I know i can buy those garage key copiers but this is more fun and i learn more.

Comment: Not the issue you asked about, but note that most remote garage door openers send a different code at each activation.  The DIP switches are like a password, and what is sent is like an encrypted password with a different salt each time.